# Partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ all of whose blocks contain only adjacencies

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there a special name for partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ all of whose blocks only contain adjacencies (mod $n$)? 
Note that these partitions are in particular non-crossing. More generally, any information about these "special" non-crossing partitions?

Example: For $n=4$, there are 12:

1.2.3.4, 12.3.4, 1.23.4, 1.2.34, 14.2.3,
123.4, 1.234, 124.3, 134.2, 14.23, 12.34, 1234.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with them, but they are quite similar to necklaces, see http://en.wikipedia.org/Necklace_(combinatorics) .

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the definition, every class here is a circular interval, so  any such $k$-partition is determined by $k$-cuts in the cyclic order, unless $k\le 1$. There are thus $2^n-n$ of these partitions.